# Multithreading dropping many tasks

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I want to do a simple job. I have a list of n elements, and want to split the list into two smaller lists and use threading to perform a simple calculation and append them to a new list. I've written some testcode and it seems to work fine when I have a small amount of elements (say 3000). But when the element list is larger (30,000), over 12-20k tasks are being dropped and the append just doesn't go through.

I've read a lot about what constitutes threadsafe, and queueing. I believe it has something to do with that, but even after experimenting with Lock() I still seem to be unable to get a threadsafe Thread.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Cheers.

```
   # Seperate thread workload
a_genes = genes[0:count_seperator]
b_genes = genes[count_seperator:genes_count]

class GeneThread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, genelist):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.genelist = genelist
    def run(self):
        for gene in self.genelist:
            total_reputation = 0
            for local_snp in gene:
                user_rsid = rsids[0]
                if user_rsid is None:
                    continue

                rep = "B"

                # If multiplier is 0, don't waste time calculating
                if not rep or rep == "G" or rep == "U":
                    continue

                importance = 1

                weighted_reputation = importance * mul[rep]
                zygosity = "homozygous_minor"

                if rep == "B":
                    weighted_reputation *= z_mul[zygosity]

                #  Now we apply the spread amplifier, we raise the score to the power of the spread number
                rep_square = pow(spread, weighted_reputation)
                total_reputation += rep_square
            try:
                with lock:
                    UserGeneReputation.append(total_reputation)
            except:
                pass

start_time = time.time()
# Create new threads
gene_thread1 = GeneThread(genelist=a_genes)
gene_thread2 = GeneThread(genelist=b_genes)

gene_thread1.daemon, gene_thread2.daemon = True, True

# Start new Threads
gene_thread1.start()
gene_thread2.start()

print(len(UserGeneReputation))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

[image: Task with 3000 vs 30,000 size list]

Comment: The threads aren't done yet. Why did you make them daemon threads? Why aren't you waiting for them to finish?

Comment: Perhaps I have a misunderstanding of what daemon does. I thought daemon meant the threads would terminate after completing their jobs?

Comment: Right, but that's absolutely not what you want. Since you have no way to know when the threads have finished their work, you need to have some other code that waits for them to finish. You can't have them autonomously finish their work and terminate because then you'll have no way to know when they're done.

Comment: You have, broadly speaking, two choices with threads. You can have them be autonomous, do their work, and then terminate themselves quietly. Or you can have them be managed by some other thread that monitors their lifetime and knows when they're done. You have a design that absolutely requires the second option (how else will you know when you have all the results you need?), yet you've chosen the first (set them for self-termination and not monitored).

Comment: Is there where something like Queue would come into play? I had a feeling the lack of something like that was causing issues for me, but even after reading a lot of other threads and documentation I don't really understand how I should syntactically apply it to my code

Comment: Just don't make the threads daemon threads. Instead, wait for both threads to finish after you start them. That's not the most sophisticated or elegant solution, but it's the one everyone learns first.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my issue. Could you please submit this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have, broadly speaking, two choices with threads. You can have them be autonomous, do their work, and then terminate themselves quietly. Or you can have them be managed by some other thread that monitors their lifetime and knows when they're done. You have a design that absolutely requires the second option (how else will you know when you have all the results you need?), yet you've chosen the first (set them for self-termination and not monitored).

Don't make the threads daemon threads. Instead, wait for both threads to finish after you start them. That's not the most sophisticated or elegant solution, but it's the one everyone learns first.

The problem with this approach is that it forces your code to be dependent on how work is assigned to threads. This can cause performance problems as you wind up having to create and destroy a thread every time you want to know when work is done, and the only way you can know that work is done is by waiting for it. Ideally, you would treat threads as an abstraction that gets work done somehow and code that has to wait for work to be finished would wait for the work itself to be finished (through some synchronization associated with the work itself) rather than wait for the thread to be finished. That way, you can be flexible about what thread does what work and don't have to keep creating and destroying threads every time you need to assign work.

But everyone learns the create/join method. And sometimes it really is the best choice. Even when you use other methods, you likely still have an outer create/join to create the threads in the first place and, typically, ensure they cleanly finish to shut down your program in an orderly way.